# Convert Namespaced Javascript Functions to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that all javascript is valid typescript but I'd like to start converting my javascript to typescript conventions.  I'm battling this one snippet of JS:

### My standard Javascript that works

```
if (MyCompany === undefined) {
    var MyCompany = {};
}
MyCompany.Uploader = MyCompany.Uploader || {};
MyCompany.Uploader.Core = function (config) {
    'use strict';
    function build() {
        console.log("building");
    }
    return {
        build: build
    };
};
var config = {this: "that};
MyCompany.Uploader.Core(config).build(); // outputs building to console
```

I've been messing with multiple approaches and I feel like I not close enough.

### My failed attempt at converting to Typescript

```
namespace MyCompany.Uploader {
    export var Core = (config:any) => {
        function build() {
            console.log("building");
        }
    };
}
let configobj = {here:"there"};
MyCompany.Uploader.Core(configobj).build();
```

This simply doesn't work.  I can't seem to access the build function.  I'm sure this is a rookie mistake.

The error I get: *Property build does not exist on type void*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you did not add an important part of your javascript code into the typescript version, and that's the return object which contains the reference for the `build` function, it should be:

```
namespace MyCompany.Uploader {
    export var Core = (config: any) {
        function build() {
            console.log("building");
        }

        return {
            build: build
        }
    };
}

let configobj = { here: "there" };
MyCompany.Uploader.Core(configobj).build();
```

You can also define interfaces for the config and the return object:

```
namespace MyCompany.Uploader {
    export interface Config {
        here: string;
    }

    export interface Builder {
        build: () => void;
    }

    export var Core = (config: Config): Builder => {
        function build() {
            console.log(config.here);
        }

        return {
            build: build
        }
    };
}

let configobj = { here: "there" };
MyCompany.Uploader.Core(configobj).build();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i got so caught up in how Typescript is different that I forgot principles that are the same between each.